# How to catch a download event by export blob document with playwright

Tags: node.js, download, path, export, playwright

My website have a editor page and export button. When i click on export button, page will gather all informations, then generate a pdf file automatically and open in new tab by Chrome Viewver.
The generate link is: blob:https://somecode

I tried to turn off Chrome Viewer and force it download pdf file. However, i cannot catch the download event.

Please guide me how to catch the download file path by Playwright using Nodejs.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the browser context's "page" event - it's a start, but not the solution, I'm stuck somewhere around that too.